# Если есть span c классом добавить родителю class (JS)

Tags: javascript

есть вот такая HTML разметка:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" placeholder="Логин">
    <div class="form-control-feedback">
        <i class="icon-user text-slate-300"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="validation-error-label">Это поле обязательно к заполнению</span>
</div>
```

Как добавить диву с классом form-group класс has-error если внутри есть span с классом validation-error-label?

Прошу помощи в реализации!

Answer (score 1):

А в чем проблема?

```
const group = document.querySelector('.form-group');
const span = group.querySelector('.validation-error-label');

if (group.contains(span)) {
    group.classList.add('has-error');
}
```